# Joomla com_installer 404 not found

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla3.0

Everytime when i click on the extensions (com_installer) in Joomla i get a 404 error.

- i updated the page from 1.5 to 3.x
- i tried to override the whole joomla installation
- now it is joomla 3.2.4 (newest)
- when i change the administrator folder the frontend is not working any more
- i have a linux root server
- nothing helpful in logfiles
- /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=manage is working, only install is not working
- newest php version
- no .htaccess in administrator folder

I think there are old files that were not deleted. Can i find the old files? Can i find the "call path" of these php files when i get the 404? access_log doesn't help either.

Comment: What do you mean by **I tried to override the whole joomla installation**? By **newest php version**, you mean 5.5.14 yes? Have you tried turning on Joomla's debug function and seeing the results? Have you edited any core Joomla files? On a side note, Joomla 3.3.1 is the latest version, not 3.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of Joomla 3.3.1, upload the administrator/components/com_installer folder to the corresponding location on your website, and see if that solves the problem. If it doesn't, then you have a completely botched migration, and you will need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update from Joomla 1.5 to either 1.6, 1.7, 2.5 or 3.x. It requires a migration because the whole setup has changed.
If you have a backup of the old 1.5 site, I recommend that you make a subdomane and a new database, and reinstall it there. If ie. images are not included in the backup, you can copy them via the FTP. When it's all restored and updated to 1.5.26, you can migrate the old side - see more here

```
http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_upgrade_from_Joomla!_1.5_to_3.x%3F
```

before you get started. Remember to always start with a fresh database and server folder
If you do not have a backup, you have to build a new page. Download pictures and files from the old page that you need and delete the rest and all database tables, so you also can here a fresh start